# Cannot export API in WebPack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am creating a library in Javascript and I am shipping it as a bundle `.js` file using *Webpack*. The following file `lib.js` serves as the entry for Webpack in order to expose all the API in the library:

```
import * as bodies from "./bodies.js";
import * as composites from "./composites.js";
import * as connections from "./connections.js";

export var bodies = {
    Body: bodies.Body,
    Pyramid: composites.Pyramid
};

export var connections = {
    Connection: connections.Connections
};
```

All the files imported basically export classes that I am referencing in `lib.js`:

```
// In bodies.js
export class Body { ... };

// In composites.js
export class Pyramid { ... };

// In connections.js
export class Connection { ... };
```

The file for bundling using Webpack is:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: './lib.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'lib-bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'out')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            /* In order to transpile ES6 */
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: { presets: ['env'] }
                }
            }
        ],  
    }
};
```

Webpack successfully bundle everything and I get my lib file in the end.

#### Problems using it

Then I use it in another project:

```
import * as mylib from "./lib/lib-bundle.js";

// Trying to use Pyramid
var pyramid = new mylib.bodies.Pyramid();
```

I use again Webpack to bundle this file into a file called `start.js` which i import in my page:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="./start.js"></script>
```

However when running this page, I get an error. If I run the F12 tools and break in the bundle where I try creating an instance of the pyramid, there i can clearly see that object mylib does not have anything I have exposed. It is empty, lacking all the objects I exposed before.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding `libraryTarget: "umd"` to the `output` section of your webpack config file

Comment: What does it do? What is it changing? Just curious...

Comment: From the [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#module-definition-systems): `This exposes your library under all the module definitions, allowing it to work with CommonJS, AMD and as global variable.`

Comment: It works :) please post an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a `libraryTarget` in the `output` section of your webpack config file.

With it the bundle will correctly export your defined values, which 
can be then imported with the various module loaders.

I suggest using `libraryTarget: "umd"` since it will add support for the most commonly used loaders.  From the [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#module-definition-systems):

> This exposes your library under all the module definitions, allowing it to work with CommonJS, AMD and as global variable.

The resulting webpack config file is as follows:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: './lib.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'lib-bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'out'),
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            /* In order to transpile ES6 */
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: { presets: ['env'] }
                }
            }
        ],  
    }
};
```

Comment: I tried the doc and it is not very easy to understand. Parameter `output`, what is it for? You added `libraryTarget` only but the doc seems like keen on suggesting developers to use `library` as well...

Comment: Basically `library` defines the name of the global object where to set all the exported values, in case you are including the library directly with a `<script>` element. E.g. `library: "Foo"` would create `window.Foo = { Body, Pyramid, Connection };` in your case